# How do I set a timeout in milliseconds for the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, proxy, timeout

I am looping through a series of proxies to check which ones of them are working, and I'm using StatusCode in the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet to check if a proxy is working.

**The ones not working take a long time to compute, and I would like to set a timeout of 10ms for the cmdlet.** Right now, I've been able to bring the timeout down to 1s, but am not able to cut it down to milliseconds. How do I do that? The line of code I'm using right now is:

```
$Test=Invoke-WebRequest -URI $Site -Proxy $proxy -TimeoutSec 1
```

Comment: Does setting `-TimeoutSec 0.001` not work?

Comment: Nope, it takes even longer then

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is TimeoutSec and is an Int32.  If you need a shorter timeout I think you're going to have to try a different approach.  Here is a pointer to a github example of using WebRequest where you can set as many parameters as you want.  More work in your script but my get you what you want.  https://gist.github.com/nolim1t/271018